# completing this code (c) if you can

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
int data;
int help;
struct node* next;
}Node;
void Nodes_maker(int nums,Node *currentnode);
int main()
{
    int count2;
    Node* root;
    Node* currentnode;
    currentnode=root;
    printf("How many numbers do you want? ");
    scanf("%d",&count2);
    Nodes_maker(count2,&currentnode);
    return 0;
}
void Nodes_maker(int nums,Node *currentnode)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nums;i++)
    {
        currentnode->next=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    } 
}
```

would someone help me complete this code?
i have the Node struct that contains 'data','help','next'.
i want to scanf a number from the user about how many numbers he wants (how many 'data' fields he wants) and making those Node structs (The 'next' field contains a pointer to another new 'data' field in another Node struct.

Comment: We are not a debugging service. What did you find out? Where is the error? Why can't you resolve it on your own, as the message is very clear?

Comment: The function expected `Node*` but you gave it `Node**` How much clearer can the compiler message get? `&currentnode` -> `currentnode`. Not that it will help in this case because you need to return a pointer from that function after allocating.

Comment: And why do you violate site-rules posting text as images, not text??

Comment: because when i first uploaded this question the text was corrupted so i uploaded the image :)

Comment: no need from you to get that angry stay calm dude it's just a question -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Nodes_maker(count2,&currentnode);
```

to this:

```
Nodes_maker(count2, currentnode);
```

and the error will go away. That is because the prototype of the function is `Nodes_maker(int nums,Node *currentnode)` and you have `Node* currentnode;`.

However, you need to work on your logic. I mean you dynamically allocate memory, but you don't return the pointer (your function returns `void`). Good luck!

---

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.

Comment: I liked the "go waya" :-)

Comment: I am not sure if I follow @Olaf, what do you mean?

Comment: "and the error will go **waya**". I really wondered what "waya" meant until I noticed it was a typo (thought it is some meme or so).

Comment: and about the void thing i am making a structs that point to other structs i have the pointer of the root so i don't have to return anything